# Javascript pseudo-enum with IDE completion

Tags: javascript, enums, ide, webstorm

Sometimes I need enum-like structures for fixed sets of string valus in Node.JS. Basically an object with keys for each enum value, and each value is a string equal to the key:

```
var State = {FOO: 'FOO', BAR: 'BAR', SOME_REALLY_LONG_NAME: 'SOME_REALLY_LONG_NAME'};
```

This enables me to type `State.S` and the IDE will suggest `State.SOME_REALLY_LONG_NAME`, and typos are practically eliminated. I can do `if (x === State.FOO)` etc.

The above syntax is however obviously not ideal due to the duplication of each literal during creation of the set of values. So I can do for example:

```
var State = _.indexBy(['FOO', 'BAR', 'SOME_REALLY_LONG_NAME'];
```

However, as soon as the object is created indirectly, the IDE (WebStorm in my case) will be unable to suggest/auto-complete the values. Sure, with JavaScript we're not very spoiled with working auto-complete anyway, but in my case it bugs me because the whole purpose of my "enum" is to simplify usage of a fixed set of strings.

There are also several enum utilities to create more proper enums, but they will suffer from the same thing. Also, if what I need is basically a fixed set of strings, more proper enums would force me into writing `State.FOO.key` to get the string value.

Is there a clever way to accomplish these really simple {key: 'key'} mappings without having to type each key twice during creation, but while still maintaining the IDE's understanding of which properties exist in the object? I'm guessing WebStorm only performs a static code analysis which goes out the window as soon as a function is called? Or is there some clever trick?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while that i used Webstorm, and it's macro-utilities, but maybe u can write a simple macro that expands your String-Array into the desired Structure.

Otherwise, you could try the Typescript-plugin. First of All: every valid JS should be valid TS (don't know exactly about ES7, and if some of the ES6 may bug the plugin).

But TS has a Enum-implementation and webstorm should therefore give you autocompletition and type-safety

Comment: I've been meaning to try TS for some time. I absolutely will. Thanks!